# Sagetex : Avoiding printing code

Tags: sagetex

I was trying to use the Sagetex code below. However when I generate the graph inside latex, I'd like to avoid the code being printed out before the graph. How could I go about doing that?

```
\begin{sageblock}
f = open("DATA", "r").readlines()
f = [i.strip() for i in f]
f = map(int, f)
g = [i+1 for i in f]
aes = f
rsa = f
vals = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
p = list_plot(zip(vals, aes), color='red', plotjoined=True) + list_plot(zip(vals, rsa), plotjoined=True)
p.axes_labels(['foo','bar'])
\end{sageblock}
\sageplot[width=.80\textwidth]{p}
```

Comment: As Samuel indicates in his answer, `sagesilent` will do it. I'd just add there are 4 environments depending on whether you want the material typeset or in your `.sage` file and you can find them on page 9 of the [documentation at CTAN](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/sagetexpackage.pdf).

Comment: The version of sagetex on CTAN is horribly outdated and should never be used. Always use the documentation included with Sage. That said, `sagesilent` is exactly the correct environment to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sagesilent` environment instead of the `sageblock`
environment for those parts you don't want printed in the document.